# Building a demo account which will reset itself periodically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We are building a simple CMS with asp.net 3.5 and mssql2005
We need to build a demo account for our customers and this will be published to public.
So, we want to reset the content of the demo account on every 2 hours.

What is the best way of building this kind of demo account?

Thanks for all responses for now.
Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for... [SQL Agent Job](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_server_agent_jobs.cfm)!  I'd give more detail, but the link has images...